# Simple R for loop not executing

Tags: r, loops

this should be an easy one, it has to be syntax but I have searched everywhere for a previously posted solution. Just trying to lower the case of variable names within tables using a loop.

The colnames command works without the "for":

```
colnames(case) <- tolower(colnames(case))
```

The for loop  works without colnames:

```
tablen<-c("account","case") 
for(x in tablen) {
print(x)
}
```

But combined

```
tablen<-c("account","case") 
for(x in tablen) {
  colnames(x) <- tolower(colnames(x))
}
```

Returns:

```
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = tolower(colnames(x))) : 
attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

Any help appreciated!

Thanks for the responses so far but the solution i am seeking is how to make 
the command:

```
 colnames(case) <- tolower(colnames(case))
```

work using a for loop. In this example the text "case" refers to a data.frame. The above command when not in a for loop changes the variable names of the case data.frame to lower case. The suggestion to create a new list of the variable names of case and lowering them using the for loop works but does not achieve the desired goal of making the above command work by referring directly to the data.frame (and not variable names in a table). It seems the colnames command just will not accept a operator like i in for (i in table).

Comment: While I don't know anything about R, I noticed in the second example you have `tablen<-c("account","case")`, but in the third (broken) example you have `tablen<("account","case")` (no `-c`). Could this be the problem?

Comment: @3ocene That isn't the problem.

Comment: Thanks 3ocene but that is a typo in my example not the problem, thanks though!!

Answer (score 3):

The key thing here is that `case` is a symbol that refers to a data.frame (or matrix, possibly). Your mistake is in thinking that the character object `"case"` *also* refers to the data.frame/matrix denoted by `case`. It does not.

For example,

```
x <- 2
```

assigned the number 2 to the object `x`. But `"x"` is just the character letter x and has no connection to the object I just defined. Probably what you want to do is put your objects in a list:

```
my_list <- list(account,case) # Note the lack of double quotes!
```

and then loop over `my_list`:

```
for (i in seq_along(my_list)){
  colnames(my_list[[i]]) <- tolower(colnames(my_list[[i]]))
}
```

A concrete example:

```
l <- list(mtcars,mtcars)
head(l[[1]])
for (i in seq_along(l)){ 
  colnames(l[[i]]) <- toupper(colnames(l[[i]]))
}
head(l[[1]])
head(l[[2]])
```

People will inevitably appear in the comments and answers suggesting that you "cheat" and use functions like `get`. Do not listen to them.

Comment: @DWhite My example does, in fact, work (I will update my answer with an example that you can copy and paste and verify for yourself). If this technique isn't working for you, that means there is something else about your data/code that you haven't shared that is causing problems.

Comment: Sorry Joran, i am trying to lower the case of all the variable names in the two data.frames "case" & "account". Your code is creating a list of the variable names of "case" and "account" and lowering the case of the names in that list
     
     tablen<-list(account,case) 
     for(x in seq_along(tablen)){
     colnames(tablen[[x]]) <- tolower(colnames(tablen[[x]]))
   }

Comment: @DWhite Right! Part of the point here is that to operate on groups of related objects in loops, the correct thing to do is to keep them in lists in the first place. You have the same access to the objects, plus you can loop over them. Leaving them as separate objects is a very common beginner mistake.

Comment: @DWhite If you want more flexibility, make it a named list: tablen <- list(account = account, case = case).

Comment: I am hoping to just loop the command

colnames(case) <- tolower(colnames(case)) 

It definitely works I just cant get the syntax correct

Comment: I defenitely agree with "Don't be tempted by `get`"!

Comment: @DWhite  colnames(case) and colnames("case") are not the same thing, that is what Joran is trying to tell you.

Comment: @DWhite More directly, `case` and `"case"` are not the same thing. Somewhere in your code you've defined `case <- ` and assigned a data frame (or something) to the name `case`. With quotes, `"case"` will always just be a string, the letter "c", followed by "a", then "s" and "e".